# Error when install Azure-Cli on my self hosted windows agent

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I have Azure DevOps pipelines using my Windows Self-hosted agent on my intranet.

I want pipelines to create universal packages and I read that I must install an extension to Azure-Cli on the agent for this.

After several errors where system team helped me setup proxy and all, I run this command in elevated command prompt:
`az extension add --name azure-devops`

I have this error message:
**Unable to get extension index.
Response body does not contain valid json. Error detail: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

What could be the issue ?

Comment: May I know that how's the things going now? Does below work around can achieve what you want? Feel free to leave comment below if you still has any questions.

Comment: I reworked the certificates that are on the server and now wait for some internal help, the answer was helpfull thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as Doris said, you need meet the most basic conditions for installing the **azure-devops** extension, that is, the version of az cli should be higher than **2.0.69**. But as far as I know, this should not be the cause of issue you encountered.

[image]

*azure cli* along with *extensions* are all built with python. So you will find that "*Error detail: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)*" is a normal JSONParseDecode error if you google it. It has many causes, like empty response, non-json response content, 500/503 error and etc. Without internet trace, I'm afraid it's hard to find the exact cause of it.

**Work around:**

========================================

To work around this issue so that you can use az devops command to achieve your goal, you can follow below steps:

**1)** Install the corresponding [whl](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/releases/download/20200401.4/azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl) file into your local machine.

**2)** Retrieve the downloaded `whl` file location, then run this command from your command line(Here I would show you the sample script I used):

```
az extension add --source C:\Users\merlinl\Downloads\azure_devops-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

**3)** Now you will see that the azure-devops installed successfully.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your CLI version.

> You must have at least `v2.0.69`, which you can verify with `az --version` command. Refer to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension).